# Django Rest Framework: How to populate ForiegnKey field with a related name?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models one BookModel and another AuthorModel. I basically want to create a foreign key field to BookModel for referencing it to the AuthorModel. And I have been able to establish this successfully.

But when I retrieve an object/record of the BookModel I get the author id instead of the whole author object. How do I do that?

Here's what I've in my code
In models.py:

```
class AuthorModel(models.Model):
     id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
     name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255)
     pen_name = models.CharField('Pen Name', max_length=255)

class BookModel(models.Model):
     id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
     name = models.CharField('Book Name', max_length=255)
     author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default='', related_name='book_authorid')
```

In serializers.py:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:   
        model = Author
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'pen_name')


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   author = AuthorSerializer() 
   class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'author')
```

The view:

```
class BookViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                       mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                       mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                       viewsets.GenericViewSet):
queryset = BookModel.objects.all()
serializer_class = BookSerializer
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

Comment: How are you retrieving and displaying the book? Show the view.

Comment: I'm using DRF mixins

Comment: Show us. Your serialisers look fine, so if you're doing it correctly, the output of your `BookSerializer` should included nested information of your author (id, name and pen_name). Just try it in your shell: `print(BookSerializer(some_book).data)`

Comment: Unrelated but: 1/ the `BookModel.author` field default should be `None` (and it should have `null=True` if it's not required), 2/ it's `related_name` is the name of the __reverse__ accessor, IOW the name under which you can get the books from an author, so naming it "book_authorid" doesn't make sense (read about reverse accessors please - FWIW, read the whole doc on models, it will save you time), and finally your design is wrong wrt/ the domain itself - a blook can have many authors (hint: who wrote the original "design patterns" book ? Yes, there are four authors...).

Answer (score 2):

The [depth](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) argument should give you the whole author object.

> The default ModelSerializer uses primary keys for relationships, but you can also easily generate nested representations using the depth option
>
> The depth option should be set to an integer value that indicates the
>   depth of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a
>   flat representation.

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   author = AuthorSerializer() 
   class Meta:
        model = Book
        depth = 1
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'author')
```